# PostSharp 4.3.21: Compiled Images Do Not Install

Tags: postsharp

I am encountering a problem with PostSharp 4.3.21 where I am selecting to install compiled images but they do not actually install.  Because of this, I am getting prompted if I would like to install every hour, even though I am choosing to install.

To be sure, this is what I am selecting:

[image]

And this is what my compiled images list looks like in PostSharp -> Options -> Compiled Images:

[image]

I have tried to uninstall [as outlined here](http://doc.postsharp.net/uninstalling) but the problem is still occurring.  Is there a consideration I am overlooking here?

Comment: The fix has been released in PostSharp 4.3.22.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, it's a known issue in PostSharp 4.3.21 and the fix is planned to be released with version 4.3.22. In the meantime, as a workaround you can select the option "Never ask me again" in the compiled images dialogue. After upgrading to 4.3.22, you can enable compiled images again in the PostSharp options dialogue within Visual Studio.

Comment: PostSharp 4.3.22 containing the fix for this issue has already been released.

Comment: 4.3.22 hasn't fixed it for me. I select the "Install compiled images" option and still "No compiled images are installed" and the dialog will appear again in one hour.

Comment: Just to confirm - did you update all PostSharp NuGet packages in your projects to 4.3.22? Updating only PostSharp VS extension will not fix the issue.